# Does r have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ here?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ = $\{1,2,3...\}$ and let p be a prime. If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are co-primes to p, does the equation:

$r = \frac{a_1a_2}{p}$ have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$ here? And how do I sufficiently answer that it hasn't?

Comment: So $p$ is a prim not being a factor of $a_1$ or $a_2$? Then you can't simplify the ratio $a_1a_2/p$ which means it's a non-integer.

Comment: $p\mid ab\Leftrightarrow p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. But you say that $p$ divides neither $a_1$ nor $a_2$.

Comment: Here's one way: (1) assume that such an $r$ exists; (2) write the equation as $rp=a_1a_2$;(3) Then $p$ is a factor of the product $a_1a_2$; (4) Then $p$ must be one of the primes in the unique factorization of $a_1a_2$;(5) But unique factorization implies that $p$ must be one of the prime facotrs of $a_1$ or $a_2$, contrary to the condition that $a_1,a_2$ are coprime to $p$.